# how to write and read to serialPort in same time?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, serial-communication

I have some device that i need to make a connection using SerialPort. 
This device receiving commands from my side and also sending data to me. 
I doing all the send/receive in same class => same thread.

I have been connected to this device and i succeed to send/receive command and data from/to this device.

One of the command that i need to send every 25 milliseconds is 'give me your status'  - that mean that i asking the device to send be back some struct with data.

In case i missing some receiving data ... when i doing 'serialPortStream.BytesToRead'  ( test if there are some data to get ) will i find on my ByteReading the older buffer that i did not rad yet ? 
how many packages i will have there in case i missed the last package that i needed to read or maybe the new data received will delete the old data that alread received before ?

Comment: You need two threads. I would create a class with an event handler eg SerialPort.DataRecieved += ____ which populates a ConcurrentQueue whenever a new byte is recieved. You can then read from this queue in your main thread and do your writing from there. Note that your packets may be out of order but you definitely won't miss any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an OnRecieveData handler that saves the data to a ConcurrentQueue or something similar.

```
namespace Test
{   class Program
    {
        const int bufSize = 2048;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Byte[] buf = new Byte[bufSize]; 
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 115200);
            sp.DataReceived += port_OnReceiveData; // Add DataReceived Event Handler

            sp.Open();

            // Wait for data or user input to continue.
            Console.ReadLine();


            sp.Close();
        }

        private static void port_OnReceiveData(object sender,  SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = (SerialPort) sender;
            switch(e.EventType)
            {
                case SerialData.Chars:
                {
                    Byte[] buf = new Byte[bufSize];
                    port.Read(buf, 0, bufSize)
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved data! " + buf.ToString());
                    break;
                }
                case SerialData.Eof:
                {
                    // means receiving ended
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```